# Extract a part of a string

Tags: javascript, string, match

I need to extract a part of a string. My goal is to extract from this string:

```
217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email
```

the content between `utmcsr=` and `|`

So the output would be : `"search_email_alerts"`.

Comment: Javascript regex is much similar to PHP regex, so I'm sure you can do it. Specially with a regex like this. Though I'd personally use `str.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email";
var newStr1 = str.split("utmcsr=");
var newStr2 = newStr1[1].split("|");
var extractedStr = newStr2[0];
```

The variable `extractedStr` will be `"search_email_alerts"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression like following:

```
var test = "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email";
var result = test.match("/utmcsr=([^|]*)\|/");
alert(result[1]); // result[1] is your desired string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways

1. [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
2. [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Here's how you can do it with regex:

```
var str= "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email";
var res = str.match(/^.*utmcsr=(.*)\|.*\|.*$/);
res[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

var str = "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email";

match = str.match(/utmcsr=(.*?)\|/);

output = match[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email"
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf("utmcsr=") + 7,str.indexOf("|"))
```

Result contains the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

```
var str = "217591953.1396968335.2.2.utmcsr=search_email_alerts|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=email";
var startIndex = str.indexOf("utmcsr=") + "utmcsr=".length;
var numOfCharsToExtract = str.indexOf("|") - startIndex;
var result = str.substring(startIndex, numOfCharsToExtract);
```